# Filtering/Searching Nested Struct Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, search, filter

I'm trying to add a search bar to the top of a grouped table. However I'm unsure how to filter through my data. The data is stored in a nested array with objects held in this format;

```
struct Group {
    var id: String
    var type: String
    var desc: String
    var avatar: String
    var name: String

    init() {
        id = ""
        type = ""
        desc = ""
        avatar = ""
        name = ""
    }
}
```

Because I get data from two sources, two arrays are nested together, this also makes it simpler to create the two sections of the grouped table. I'll note, they both use the same Group struct.

```
self.masterArray = [self.clientArray, self.departmentArray]
```

This "masterArray" is then used to populate the table. Filtering/searching a single array isn't too difficult, but how do I search through a nested array?

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

}
```

**EDIT:** 
I've finally got things working, courtesy of @appzYourLife.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print("Searching for:" + searchText)
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        filterArray = masterArray
    } else {
        filterArray = [ clientArray.filter { $0.name.range(of: searchText) != nil }] + [ departmentArray.filter { $0.name.range(of: searchText) != nil } ]
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, it was unclear to me that the nested arrays were an intentional design decision

Comment: I've edited the question, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Aloogy Regarding edit: your `.filter{ ... }` closure in its current form contains an incorrect argument type: the closure expects _elements_  that are arrays themselves (`[Group]` elements). Try exchanging the above to `filterArray = masterArray.flatten().filter(....`. (Or, just: `filterArray = masterArray.flatten().filter { $0.id.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString) }`). Also, have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial).

Comment: I actually get the exact same error when using flatten()

Comment: @Aloogy Ah, I suspect the type of `filterArray` is `[[Group]]`, in which case the filtering operation must yield an object of type `[[Group]]`. Try `filterArray = masterArray.map { $0.filter { $0.id.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString) } }`.

Comment: @dfri You might be on to something, I'm not getting the usual errors now, which is most certainly a step in the right direction - I'm now just getting `value of type String has no member containsString` which is odd. I've definitely imported Foundation etc..

Comment: @Aloogy: Yeah that's odd, especially if you are certain that your have included `import Foundation`. Anyway, that's just the filtering part, which you should be able to solve using an alternative method (e.g. the one in your edit above).

Comment: @dfri: Ended up being a Swift-3 related issue, the syntax how now changed a little, and clearly the migration helper hasn't been taught to pick up on `containsString` and `rangeOfString`.

Comment: @Aloogy I see, glad you sorted it out. For future reference: it can be a good idea to include what Swift version you are using in the footer of your question (Swift still change quite much between versions, especially major ones). Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
struct Group {
    let id: String = ""
    let type: String = ""
    let desc: String = ""
    let avatar: String = ""
    let name: String = ""
}

let clients = [Group(), Group(), Group(), Group()]
let departmens = [Group(), Group(), Group(), Group()]

let clientsAndDepartments = [clients, departmens]
```

You can search inside `clients` and `department` writing

```
let results = (clients + departmens).filter { $0.id == "123" }
```

[image]

### Update #1

Now understand that you want to filter both arrays but as result you still want something like this `[[Group]]`.

So here's the code

```
var filterArray = [clients.filter { $0.name == "White" }] + [departmens.filter { $0.name == "White" }]
```

### Update #2

If you want to search for string inclusione the use this code

```
var filterArray = [ clients.filter { $0.name.rangeOfString("White") != nil }] + [ departmens.filter { $0.name.rangeOfString("White") != nil } ]
```

Comment: When I try and use this I get `Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(@noescape (Group) throws -> Bool)'`

Comment: @Aloogy: I added a screenshot of my playground, as you can see it does work. You should check the differences with your code. Can you add a screenshot of your code in Xcode showing the code I suggested and the error message you received?

Comment: [Here's both the ways I'm trying to do this, including yours.](http://i.imgur.com/ZSjgcqV.png)

Comment: @Aloogy: ok, I have seen your screenshot. 3 questions: __1)__ how is `filteredArray` defined? __2)__ How is `clientArray` defined? __3)__ How is `departmentArray` defined?

Comment: `var filterArray = [[Group]]()
var clientArray: [Group] = []
var departmentArray: [Group] = []`

Comment: @Aloogy: Updated, please take a look.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Aloogy: Please take a look at my `Update #2`

Comment: Even better, thats exactly what I was going to do next. Awesome stuff, thanks.

Comment: I'd just like to add for anyone using Swift-3, the syntax has changed, and in @appzYourLife's second example,  `.rangeOfString("White")` is now `.range(of: "White")`.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `.flatten()` to flatten your array prior to filtering it for whatever search criteria you want to use. E.g.

```
struct Group {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    init(_ id: String, _ name: String) { self.id = id; self.name = name }
    /* .... */
}

let clientArray = [Group("a", "John"), Group("b", "Jane"), Group("c", "Phil")]
let departmentArray = [Group("a", "Foo"), Group("b", "Bar"),
                       Group("c", "Baz"), Group("d", "Bax")]

let arr = [clientArray, departmentArray]

// find some id
let searchForId = "c"
let hits = arr.flatten()
    .filter { $0.id.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString) }

print(hits)
    // [Group(id: "c", name: "Phil"), Group(id: "c", name: "Baz")]
```

From the edits of your questions, it seems, however, that you want the resulting filtered array to be of the same nested array type as the "master" array. In such case, the following is a more appropriate approach:

```
/* ... */

// find some id but keep [[Group]] type
let searchText = "c"
let hits = arr.map { $0.filter { $0.id.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString) } }

print(hits)
    // [[Group(id: "c", name: "Phil")], [Group(id: "cc", name: "Baz")]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map over each of the arrays, and filter them independently:

```
self.masterArray.map{ subarray in 
    subarray.filter { element in
        trueWhenElementShouldStay(element)
    }
}
```

P.S. I suspect masterArray should NOT be an instance variable, it would be more appropriate as a local variable instead.

Comment: Do you have an idea why something like this won't work? 
`func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if(searchText.isEmpty){
            filteredArray = masterArray
        } else {
            filteredArray = masterArray.filter { subarray in
                subarray.filter { element in
                    return element.name.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText.lowercaseString)
                }
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }`

Thank you very much for your help.